# Is it bad design to pass reference of collections in constructor?

Tags: java

I encounter many times of similar code:

```
class AClass{
    private Iterable<String> list;
    public AClass(Iterable<String> list){ this.list = list; }
    ...
}
```

In this code, a reference of Iterable is passed to AClass directly. The end result is equivalent to directly expose list reference to outside. Even if you make AClass.list final, it still allows code from outside AClass to modify the content of the list, which is bad.

To counter this, we will do a defensive copy in the constructor.

However, this kind of code is very common. Besides performance consideration, what's the intension for people to write this kind of code?

Comment: What are you proposing as an alternative that does not have this hazard, if the object needs a collection someone else provides?

Comment: It's called "Dependency Injection" and is perfectly normal. It's expected you're smart enough to know you're passing in an object in Java and what happens if you then modify that object later. If you're dead set on requiring that people not be that smart, make a copy. Of course, often it won't be a Collection of immutable `String` Objects ...

Comment: Even with the defensive copy, the objects in the list may be mutable which means they can be changed outside the control of AClass. The question you need to ask is what is the list for. Blindly applying defensive copy is just as bad as blindly reusing the list by ref. (though defensive copy gets you closer to immutable objects which have simpler threading symmantics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with that pattern. If the class represents objects that operate on a list (or an iterable) then it's natural to provide that list to the constructor. If your class can't handle changes to the underlying collection, then it needs to be fixed or documented. Making a copy of the collection is one way to fix that.

Another option is to change the interface so that only immutable collections are allowed:

```
public AClass(ImmutableList<MyObject> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
    ...
```

You would need some kind of ImmutableList-class or interface of course.

Depending on the use and users of your classes you could also avoid making copies by documenting the known "weakness":

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param objects list of objects this AClass-object operates on.
 *                The list should not be modified during the lifetime 
 *                of this object
 */
public AClass(List<MyObject> objects) ...
```

Comment: It would be good to note that the `ImmutableList` interface comes from Google's Guava project.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro: Actually I did not mean to reference Guava specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, if it is your own code/small team, it is often just quicker, easier and less memory and CPU intensive to do things this way. Also, some people just don't know any better!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) for a familiar idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good practice to make a copy, not only because other people can then modify your values, but also for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is being used internally as is pointed by other answers it should not be a problem. But if you are exposing as an API then there are two options:

First is to create a defensive copy and then return it

Second would be to create a `UnmodifiableCollection` and then return it and document the fact that trying to change anything in the collection may result in exception.

But the first option is more preferable.